# ruby import data from another file

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby file with jsons listed like this

```
 class TestIng
   attr_accessor :a, :b
  def data
    @a ={

    }
    @b = {

    }
  end 
 end 
end
```

I have another file where I need to import this data and use the factory based on the name used in that file i.e if the file outputs factorya, it should use factorya json data etc. Here is what I tried so far

```
    variableUnderTest
    require_relative /data.rb'
    @setup = TestIng.new
    @setup.data
    # variableUnderTest can be factorya/factoryb etc. This is where I am not sure how to get the correct value from another file
    return @setup.variableUnderTest
```

New to Ruby. Appreciate any guidance here. Also is there a better way to achieve this

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does this have to do with JSON? There is no JSON in your code. Also, why do you want to pass data between Ruby objects as JSON instead of, you know, Ruby? You are asking "is there a better way to achieve this", but you haven't really explained what "this" is that you want to achieve.

Comment: Unfortunately I am given code like this to fix where there is a file with several constants defined in multiple formats which I have to import and use in another file.

Comment: It is still unclear what you are asking. "there is a file with several constants defined in multiple formats which I have to import and use in another file" – There are no constants in the code you showed. What does it mean for constants to be defined in "multiple formats"? What do you mean by "import"? Ruby doesn't have imports.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `TestData::TestData.new.setup_list1`? The exception suggest you do the following `TestData::TestData.setup_list1`.

Comment: edited the question. The ruby code has where i am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestData::TestIng.new.setup_list1

upd:

maybe you can try to do anything like this?

```
module TestData
  class TestIng
    attr_accessor :a, :b

    def setup
      @a = {k: 1}
      @b = {c: 10}
    end
  end
end

test_data = TestData::TestIng.new
test_data.setup
puts test_data.a
puts test_data.a
puts test_data.b
puts test_data.b
```

Comment: TestData::TestIng::setup_list1 does not work because this method is instance method. If you want self class method you should define it as: def self.setup_list1 and  then use it: TestData::TestIng.setup_list1

Comment: I just get an array when I print  TestData::TestIng.new.setup_list1. It is not having the @factory keys I am looking for

Comment: could you give an example of expected result of your code?

Comment: I have the updated the question to the point where I got in my code so far.